# I need help outputting 'greater than' and 'less than' characters using dataweave in xml format

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

i have the following dataweave code

```
%dw 2.0
output xml writeDeclaration=false
---
'a:b': '<'
```

the current output is

```
<a:b>&lt;</a:b>
```

however my desired output is

```
<a:b><</a:b>
```

is anyone has any ideas, any help is appreciated! thank you

Comment: Aled is correct - your 'desired output' is not valid XML. If you want to output a tag with the single-character value '<' then you can do that - the correct XML representation is <a>&lt;</a>. The receiving application will receive the value '<', not the value '&lt;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to do that. The output is XML, and in the XML specification a lone `<` character **must** be encoded as `&lt;`. [Other characters](http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html) are also restricted from appear as text in an XML document.

Having said that, you can generate that literal character if the element is in a CData block. You can create a [CData blockin DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-xml#format_xml_cdata) by coercing a String to CData.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output xml writeDeclaration=false
---
'a:b': '<' as CData
```

Output:

```
<a:b><![CDATA[<]]></a:b>
```

Comment: thanks aled - my overall goal was to actually create a <!CDATA> tag as you have provided. i should have been more specific with my example. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a string output, the workaround is replace the "&lt" with "<". This is just a workaround if you don't want to use CDATA

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
write('a:b': '<',"application/xml", { "writeDeclaration": false}) 
     replace "&lt;" with "<"
```

**Output:**

```
<a:b><</a:b>
```

Comment: ...but the resulting output is not valid XML.

Comment: good idea thanks ray - i have provided feedback to aled above about the answer i was after