# how to replace &amp with & in XML payload

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Trying to remove "&amp" and replace with "&". When I tried to remove "&" from payload, getting &; and &lt

**Dataweave**

```
 %dw 2.0
    output application/xml
    ---
    "root":
    write(payload, "application/xml") replace "&amp;" with '&'
```

**Input**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
        <entry>
           <ID>123</ID>
            <Name>Games &amp; Sams</Name>
            <Address>133 Washington Square</Address1>
            <State>PO</State>
        </entry>
    </root>
```

**Expected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <entry>
       <ID>123</ID>
       <Name>Games & Sams</Name>
       <Address>133 Washington Square</Address1>
       <State>PO</State>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Comment: This has been answered before; the & symbol isn't valid in the content of the XML unless wrapped in CDATA.

Comment: Can you please direct me to CDATA link here for reference?

Comment: I tried with text/plain. It is working but unable to convert to XML again. Is there a possibility to convert from text to XML                                                                                      %dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
write(payload, "application/xml") replace "&amp;" with '&'

Comment: @anonymous, please refer this answer from from this URL-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67446584/i-need-help-outputting-greater-than-and-less-than-characters-using-dataweave

Comment: @aled may be this link helps for &lt and &gt https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T000054GsWr/hi-please-someone-can-help-me-how-to-convert-below-input-to-xml-using-dataweave-2